# stacked horizontal chart

Tags: css, html

I want to have a chart that is something like this:

http://jcharts.sourceforge.net/samples/stackedBar.html#Horizontal+Stacked+Bar+Chart

I am challenged on how to do this in a table and or with divs and so on. Doing a simple chart without more than one section seems easier. I am not sure exactly where to start, what approach to take, or where to look on the web. I would like to keep it simple.

It seems I have found a few plugins and so on, but I would like to just write the html/css myself if possible. I also work with Ruby and some of the plugins are the wrong language ..

Answer (score 1):

Those charts are images. To reproduce them with pure HTML/CSS would be a challenge and probably not worth it.

If you find a plugin (maybe JavaScript) that works for you, use it.

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal charting is pretty simple.  You can always have a div within a div to represent the stacked bars so the first div would have a background colour of blue and within that div you will have a background colour of yellow.

The 3d charts you can have a background image for each bar and different inner divs with different background image colour to give you stacked colour variant charts

This layout should be all done with DIVS and absolute positioning